# How to display a pdf in a web browser without any possibility of saving, printing or sharing

Tags: android, pdf, webview

I need to show a pdf file in an android app, so that the users will not be able to save or share it, nor Google will keep a copy of it.

I have thought of using iframes, but this allows the users to open the pdf file in a browser (and print or share it from there).

Here is what I came up with:

```
pdfView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
WebSettings settings = pdfView.getSettings();
settings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
pdfView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
pdfView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
settings.setAllowFileAccess(false);
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
settings.setSupportZoom(true);
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
settings.setSaveFormData(false);
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

String html = "<iframe src=\"http://docs.google.com/gview?url=" + 
    path + "&embedded=true&wmode=opaque\"" +
    "style=\"width:600px; height:900px;\" scrolling=\"no\"" + 
    "frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";

pdfView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

The solution does not have to be based on embedding and showing in a web browser.
I need to support API 16+, so using PdfRenderer is not an option.

Comment: the problem is no matter what you do, the user could always take a screenshot of whatever you are showing them, getting around your security

Comment: Does it absolutly have too be in a webview?

Comment: No, it does not have to be in a webview.

Comment: It helped me to add
    sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts"
inside the <iframe> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helped me to add sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts" inside the iframe tag.